# Studying Python from a book and I can't debbug this exercise

Tags: python, dictionary

I am working on an exercise about dictionaries in Python when i run the code it returns an error that I can't debug. I dont know if I am using the wrong operators at the dictionaries because [] are used in lists too

```
states = [
    'Oregon''OR',
    'Florida''FL',
    'California' 'CA',
    'New York''NY',
    'Michigan' 'MI'
]

cities = [
    'CA' 'San Francisco',
    'MI' 'Detroit',
    'FL' 'Jacksonville'
]

cities['NY'] = 'New York'
cities['OR'] = 'Portland'

print '_' * 10
print "NY State has: ", + cities['NY']
print "OR State has: ", + cities['OR']


print '_' * 10
print "Michigan's abbreviation is: " + states['Michigan']
print "Florida's abbreviation is: " +  states['Florida']

print '_' * 10
print "Michigan has: ", cities[states['Michigan']]
print "Florida has: ", cities[states['Florida']]

print '_' * 10
for state, abbrev in states.items():
    print "%s is abbreviated %s" % (state, abbrev)

print '_' * 10
for abberv, city in cities.items():
    print "%s has the city %s" % (abbrev, city)

print '_' * 10
for state, abbrev in states.items():
    print "%s state is abbreviated %s and has city %s" %(state, abbrev, cities[abbrev])


print '_' * 10
```

i get this new message

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WL6n1.png)

Comment: Please copy and paste the code and error message into your question rather than posting screenshots.

Comment: Please take the [tour], read [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.

Comment: Please put effort into your questions and solving the problem yourself. Is your question about solving the error or how you're supposed to debug whatever error that is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add + to concat the strings.

print " something about michigan " + states['michigan']

or

print " something about michigan ", states['michigan']

Comment: Thank you for help.
Although now some new errors pop up which is strange because I am doing this exercise by a book and I copy everything that I saw exactly, checked already for spelling mistakes

Comment: You have lots and lots of typos in your code. (abberv, abbrev...), also you are most certainly mixing up `[]` and `{}`, as well as missing some `:`. You should really be more carefully when retyping code from exercises.

Comment: I suppose you mean that when I am creating a dictionary I should use { } instead of [ ]. As for the missing : you are right but I removed them on purpose.Apart from that all the other code has been copied and paste straight from the book itself to check it again and it is still not function able and it is returning the same mistakes as at the beginning

Comment: if you want to learn python go to MIT Open Course-ware and do the Introduction to Computer Science.  Its all python and is an excellent way to learn.

Answer (score 0):

Please don't post screenshots of code...

You are missing a `+` in line 35, but since you only posted an image, I won't type the correct line for you.

Comment: Thank you for your help.
I am new at the community didn't know that I am not supposed to post printscreened code.

Comment: No problem. Just think of this: for a more complicated error, someone would have to re-type your whole code to check it locally. Usually, nobody will do that. Since you seek help, make it as easy as possible to provide you with help. See [ask] and [mcve], as already suggested.